# Laravel: reverse the result of pagination query

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am using Laravel 5.6 and I want to reverse the result of the pagination query. This is what I am trying to do:

```
$chats = Chats::where('message_id', $message_id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
if(!empty($chats)) {
    $data['messages'] = $chats->reverse()->values();
    $data['status'] = 200;
    $data['create_user_id'] = Auth::id();
}else{
    $data['error'] = "No chats available";
}
```

But it removes the pagination from the result. Lets suppose I have these 10 values in table

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Now I want `6, 7, 8, 9, 10` in first page result and `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` in second page result, specifically in that order.

How do I get this? Please help!!!

Comment: What does "it removes the pagination from the result" mean? What does your controller return?

Answer (score 3):

Well,

```
->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
```

in your paginate query, should give you

```
`10, 9, 8, 7, 6`
```

Then just reverse those in the output to get

```
`6, 7, 8, 9, 10`
```

Code example:

```
// $chats here are instance of LengthAwarePaginator
// so we use ->items() to get the array of paginated objects
$chats = Chats::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
$data = [];

if ($chats->count()) {
    $data['reverseModels'] = collect($chats->items())->reverse();
    $data['reverseIds'] = collect($chats->items())->reverse()->pluck('id');
} else {
    $data['error'] = 'Error';
}
```

Comment: I am creating it as an API. I need to give the result as it is.

Comment: In controller, it won't allow me to reverse the result in pagination. Please let me know if you have any working example.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function to view attendance of an employee , here i am paginating the results by taking dates in descending order. Here i am getting the correct results, ie new attendance to old attendance.

```
    public function viewAttendance($id){
        $q = Attendance::where('emp_id','=',$id)
           ->orderBy('date','desc')
           ->select('attendance.*')
           ->paginate(10);
        return $q;
    }
```